# Instancing a parameterized cell in Xilinx schematic

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I have a parameterized cell - a n-bit register, defined as:

```
module Register #(parameter n = 16)(
    output reg [n-1:0] OUTPUT,
    input [n-1:0] INPUT,
    input RST, EN, CLK);
// bla bla bla
endmodule
```

In a **Xilinx Verilog Module** I could instance this n bit register like so:

```
Register #(8) REG1 (OUT, IN, RST, EN, CLK);
```

(as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668143/how-do-i-define-a-module-with-a-parameter-in-verilog)).

How do I instance this register with let's say 8 bit INPUT/OUTPUT in a **Xilinx Schematic**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately in **Xilinx Schematics** instances are fixed; therefor you cannot set parameters. Your best option would be to create a new module, possibly named `Register_8bit`, that sets `n` as a parameter in the module. Then separate sized modules can be named separately, but only the inner parameter must be changed.

```
module Register_8bit (
    parameter n = 8;
    output reg [n-1:0] OUTPUT,
    input [n-1:0] INPUT,
    input RST, EN, CLK);
// bla bla bla
endmodule
```

This allows the most reuse of code while still allowing the benefits of the top level schematic view.