# How to pass vector to module without changing value?

Tags: verilog

I want to write an array multiplier and I have two modules ArrayMultiplier,Top.

In the Top module I have three array result, a1, a2.

```
module Top();
   reg [4*5-1:0] a1;
   reg [5*3-1:0] a2;
   wire [4*3-1:0] result;
   integer i,j;
   initial begin
     for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1) begin
       for(j=0;j<5;j=j+1) begin
         a1[i*5+j]=1'b1;
       end
     end
     for(i=0;i<5;i=i+1) begin
       for(j=0;j<3;j=j+1) begin
         a2[i*3+j]=1'b1;
       end
     end
   end  
   ArrayMultiplier #(4,5,3) test(result,a1,a2);
endmodule
```

And ArrayMultiplier:

```
module ArrayMultiplier(result,a1,a2);
  parameter a1R=0;
  parameter a1C=0;//a1C=a2R.
  parameter a2C=0;
  output reg[(a1R*a2C)-1:0] result;
  input [(a1R*a1C)-1:0] a1;
  input [(a1C*a2C)-1:0] a2;
  integer i,j,k;
  initial begin
    //$display("a1R=%d a1C=%d a2C=%d",a1R,a1C,a2C);
    for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)
      for(j=0;j<5;j=j+1)
        $display("%d a1=%d ",i,a1[i*5+j]);
    for(i=0;i<a1R;i=i+1) begin
      for(j=0;j<a2C;j=j+1) begin
        result[i*a2C+j]=0;
      end
    end
    for(i=0;i<a1R;i=i+1) begin
      for(j=0;j<a2C;j=j+1) begin
        for(k=0;k<a1C;k=k+1) begin
          result[i*a2C+j]=result[i*a2C+j]+(a1[i*a1C+k]*a2[k*a2C+j]);
          $display("res=%d a1=%d a2=%d",result[i*a2C+j],a1[i*a1C+k],a2[k*a2C+j]);
        end
      end
    end
  end
endmodule
```

I have initialized a1, a2 but when I pass them to ArrayMultiplier module they just have x value.

I don't know what is happening.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are not **overriding the parameters** of `ArrayMultiplier` module.

By default, the parameters like `a1R`,`a1C` and `a2C` are initialized to `0`, if these are *not* overridden while **instantiating module**, then the vectors `a1` and `a2` are created of **zero size**.

Looking at your `Top` module, mapping `a1R=4`, `a1C=5` and `a2C=3`, and instantiating the module, solves the error of displaying `x`. The module instantiation is as follows:

```
ArrayMultiplier #(4,5,3) test(result,a1,a2);
```

This solves your problem. For more information on **parameterized modules**, have a look at [Parameterized Modules](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/para_modules1.html) and [Module Parameters in Verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668143/how-do-i-define-a-module-with-a-parameter-in-verilog) links.

Answer (score 2):

First, based on your code, you never set `a1R`, `a1C`, or `a2C` to values other than 0, meaning nothing in your `ArrayMultiplier` will be multiplied (and your vector indices are bad). Either change the parameter values in `ArrayMultiplier`, or pass them in from your `Top` module.

Secondly, your multiplier should probably be using an `always@(*)` block, rather than an `initial` block.